# jQuery Deny Draggable Elements Already in Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some jQuery divs with the droppable class "dropBox"; I want to accept divs with the class "teamBox", but only if they don't already exist in the droppable "dropBox" container.  I've tried doing this by using the `over` event for the dropBox, but found that checking if dropBox contained the draggable element always returned true.  I also tried placing a condition in the `accept` portion of the dropBox, but I had the same problem.  Code for both attempts below.  Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="panel-heading">Teams</div>
<div class="panel-body teamContainer">
    @foreach($teamContent as $teamID => $teamName)
        <div id="{{ $teamID }}" class="teamBox">
            <h5><b>{{ $teamName }}</b></h5>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">Twitter</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @if(!empty($twitterContent))
        @foreach($twitterContent as $twitterID => $screenName)
            <span class="{{ $twitterID }}">
                <h5>{{ '@' . $screenName }}</h5>
            </span>
            <div id="{{ $twitterID }}" class="dropBox"></div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">Facebook</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @if(!empty($facebookContent))
        @foreach($facebookContent as $pageID => $pageName)
            <span class="{{ $pageID }}">
                <h5>{{ $pageName }}</h5>
            </span>
            <div id="{{ $pageID }}" class="dropBox"></div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

jQuery Attempt Using `over`

```
$(".teamBox").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 1,
});

$(".dropBox").droppable({
    accept: '.teamBox',
    over: function(event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        var over = $(this);
        if($(over).find($(draggable).attr('id')))
        {
            //Always logs as disabling
            console.log("Disabling");
            $(over).droppable('disable');
        }
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(this).append($(dropped).clone());
        $(".dropBox .teamBox").addClass("item");
        $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable");
        $(".item").draggable({
            zIndex: 1,
        });
    }
});
```

jQuery Attempt using `accept`

```
$(".teamBox").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 1,
});

$(".dropBox").droppable({
    accept: function(draggable) {
        if($(this).has($(draggable).attr('id'))) {
            //Always returns false
            console.log("Returning false");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(this).append($(dropped).clone());
        $(".dropBox .teamBox").addClass("item");
        $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable");
        $(".item").draggable({
            zIndex: 1,
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
Ended up coming up with a solution that worked for me.  Here's [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e40tdL1t/).  Keep in mind that I'm using Laravel Spark, so there's Laravel blade syntax within the HTML that doesn't compile correctly in the Fiddle.  However, looking at the code may give you an idea of how to create a drag-and-drop system with cloning and denial of duplicated draggable items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this in `draggable` using `revert`:

```
$(".teamBox").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 1,
    revert: function(){
        return $(".dropBox .teamBox").length ? true : false;
    }
});
```

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert

> Whether the element should revert to its start position when dragging stops.
>
> **Function:** A function to determine whether the element should revert to its start position. The function must return `true` to revert the element.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  Unfortunately, it doesn't work for this situation since there are many instances of both .dropBox and .teamBox.  However, I didn't know about revert before, so that may help me going forward.

Comment: If that is the case, assign an attribute or class to the draggable when it's dropped into droppable. This will allow you to check for that attribute or selector and determine whether to revert or not.

Comment: @HannahHunt another idea would be a global variable that is assigned `true` or `false` when an item is dragged in or out of your droppable. Many ways to do these. In the end, you just need to check a flag someplace to see if an item already exists and revert or not.

Comment: After quite a few more hours of working on this, I figured it out.  Ended up modifying the droppable box's accept function rather than using revert, but your advice put me on the right track and I did end up using a boolean to determine whether or not to accept the value.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @HannahHunt Awesome! It might be useful to others to edit your post, and ammend it with an update of what you ended up doing to reach your answer and the final code. Or drop it in a Fiddle so others that run across this can see.

Comment: Good idea.  Editing to add a Fiddle of the solution.  Thanks again!